# How to change some fields' values in models.Model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here's the code snippet for changing the `size` field after a raw query via django's model:

```
ress = models.Resource.objects.raw("select id, size from `main_table`")
for res in ress:
    size = res.size
    res.size = res.size + "anything"
    print res.size # Here it prints the changed string of size field.
for res in ress:
    print res.size # it prints the original string of size field.
```

I'm wondering why the `size` field remains the original one at the second loop even after I changing it at the first loop? Could anyone give me some idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why are you using `raw()`? You should avoid this because it makes your code unportable. Use the ORM: `ress = Resource.objects.all().values('pk','name')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occurring because `ress` is a RawQuerySet and is evaluated lazily. Each time you loop through it, the database is queried. If you want `ress` to act like a normal list that you can manipulate without having to save it, simply turn it into a list like so:

```
ress = list(models.Resource.objects.raw("select id, size from `main_table`"))
```